# Fit a joint distribution with empirical margins and copula by R

Tags: r, joint-distribution, copula

Knowing that the data of two stocks have a Copula and want to get the joint distribution.
I want to use empirical marginal distribution, but I don't know how to do that by using the function mvdc. Hope you guys can give some hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn’t that just the data for each variable?

Comment: the function is mvdc(normalCopula(0.75), c("norm", "exp"),
                        list(list(mean = 0, sd =2), list(rate = 2))). and I am confused about the second part, if i want to use empirical distribution, what should i do to replace the "norm","exp"

Comment: solved it with emp